# Overlaping elements on different columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a menu layout (design layout below) but I am having trouble trying stop elements inside from overlapping. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7. The problem only occurs on desktop and not mobile. I made one "menubox" (basically one dish) and made two copies of the whole thing (3 in a row), each taking 4 columns. The one on the right ends up overlapping the one on it's left a little, and they're not centered as 3. Included is an image of the problem.

[image]

[image: layout]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html body {
  height: 100%;
}

.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}


.navbar {
  background-color: #ff8300;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navspace {

  right: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;

}


.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}




.thumbnails {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#myCarousel {
  width: 980px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 654px;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;

  
  
}



.carousel-control {
  height: 600px;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.banner {
  background: url(../images/banner1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 980px;
  height: 654px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.banner2 {
  background: url(../images/banner2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 980px;
  height: 654px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  
}

.banner3 {
  background: url(../images/banner3.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 980px;
  height: 654px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  
}

.banner p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 440px;
  left: 20px;
}

.banner h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 20px;
  top: 420px;
}

.bodyimg {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bodytext1 {
  color: #ff8300;
}

.bodytext2 {
  color: #ff8300;
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.bodytext3 {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin-top: 60px
}

.bodytext4 {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin-top: 60px
}

.socialpadding {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.centersocial {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.contactinfo {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin: 200px 0px 0px auto;
  
}


/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */

.formarea {
  background-color: #ff8300;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 484px;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.formlabel {
  color: #fff;
}

#inputMessage {
  height: 200px;
}


.btn {
  background-color: #fcb972;
  border-color: #ff9300;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.btn:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.btn:onclick {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.messageform {
  height: 50px;
}

.google-maps {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.google-maps iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.formarea2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

#inputPostal {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:3%;
}


.formpostal {
  color: #ff8300;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menubg {
  background-color: #ff8300; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 125px;


}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.cartbtn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 96%;

}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;

}

.menubox {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 321px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;


}

.menubox a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item1 {
  background: url(../images/menu1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

}

.menubox img {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.menubox:hover .item1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.menubox:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.foot {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #ff8300;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 150px auto 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff8300;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navspace {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    left: 120px;
    top: 30px;
  }

  .navbar-collapse {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    height: 300px;

  }

  .foot {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff8300;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  footer {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .contactinfo {
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #myCarousel.carousel {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  }

  .carousel-control {
    height: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .findus {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .centersocial {
    position: relative;
  }
  .bodytext4 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 100px auto 5px auto;
  }
  .bodytext3 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 60px auto 5px auto;
  }



}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .formarea {
    background-color: #ff8300;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 484px;
    margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }




}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}

/* additional */

.row, #myCarousel, .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Peperoni Pizzeria</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>







      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top rounded-bottom">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="navspace" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="navspace" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a class="navspace" href="location.html">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a class="navspace" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <!-- Put here your menu items -->
              </ul>

            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">

            <div class="formarea2">
              <form> 

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="formpostal" for="inputPostal">Input Postal Code:</label>
                  <input type="postal" class="form-control" id="inputPostal" placeholder="i.e 450894">

                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 menubg col-centered">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <a href="#"><img class="cartbtn" src="images/cart.png" alt="cart"></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <h2>Appetisers/Sides</h2>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">

                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="menubox">

                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="item1">
                        <img href="#" src="images/addtocart.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp; Rucola Salad &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $10</h3>
                    </a>


                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="menubox">

                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="item1">
                        <img href="#" src="images/addtocart.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp; Rucola Salad &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $10</h3>
                    </a>


                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="menubox">

                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="item1">
                        <img href="#" src="images/addtocart.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp; Rucola Salad &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $10</h3>
                    </a>


                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 foot img-responsive">

                <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
                  Copyright © 2017 Peperoni Pizzeria. All Rights Reserved.
                </footer>


              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Your `.menubox` elements have a fixed `width` of `321px` in your CSS. You'll need to make that percentage-based.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Such a simple fix and a dumb mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-centered {
  padding:0px;
}
.col-sm-4.add-some-class {
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
}
.menubox{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 315px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
}
```

1-This will 100% work for you
i applied this then send you the final code.
thankyou.